# Rows has more than Columns

Tags: reverse-puzzling

> Friend: Hey! want to see what I'm solving?
>
> Me: Yeah sure.
>
> Friend: *showing an image*
>
> Me: Oh, come on, why do I wanna do reverse puzzling again!?
>
> Friend: Oh, just put it on a Q and A website then.

This was the image:

[image: Rows: 5 0s, 131, 212111, 1111131, 12121, 31; Columns: 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 3, 11, 0, 0, 5, 111, 31, 0, 0, 31; 20×10 grid]

**Question:** What were they solving?

**Bonus Question:** Try solving it.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like [tag:reverse-puzzling] to me. There's nothing that needs to be reconstructed, because the puzzle is just given to us directly. And the puzzle itself is fairly trivial, too. (Also, why the five 0s? You could've just made the grid smaller, no?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were solving

> a nonogram, with the given clues being the row and column clues

and this was the answer:

> [image]